# Left- and right-aligned text on the same line in a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's common for menus on desktop apps to show the name of the action on the left and the keyboard shortcut on the right, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xju6T.png).

I want to do the same thing in a Bootstrap dropdown. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried several things. Here is the code for the two closest tries and [a link to a demo](http://bootply.com/99290).

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Try 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span>Label</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span>Long long long long long label</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Try 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="pull-left">Label</span><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="pull-left">Long long long long long label</span><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Again, [here's a link to a demo](http://bootply.com/99290).

Both Try 1 and Try 2 work for short labels, but not for long labels.

With Try 1, the problem is that [the label and the shortcut overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W5uC.png).

With Try 2, the problem is that [the shortcut gets pushed to another line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ettuQ.png), and there is also some weirdness with hovering over the items.

What I want is for it to all be on one line, so you see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOEM9.png) (that image is just a fake that I made in GIMP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried many ways to get the result with Bootstrap classes, but I think you'll need a bit of custom CSS. Here is an example :

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Label <span class="kbd text-muted">Alt+S</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Not labeled</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Long long long long long label <span class="kbd text-muted">Alt+L</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 70px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a > span.kbd {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 3px;
}
```

**[Updated Bootply](http://bootply.com/99382)**

Answer (score 2):

Can you look at http://bootply.com/99291

and look this code :

```
  <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Try 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span>Label</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-muted pull-right">Alt+P</span><span style="white-space: normal;">Long long long long long label</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Your very long text is wrap in a span with `<span style="white-space: normal;">`

Does it render better for what you want ?

Comment: I should have been more clear in my original post, I want it to all be on one line. I'll edit my question. Thanks!